# How to map normal mode to modifier key on keyboard in vim (say Alt)?

Tags: linux, vim, key-bindings

I want to make my workflow in vim a little bit faster for me, by working all the time in insert mode, with executing normal mode commands(keybindings), when I hold some modifier key, say alt.

So, for example, I'm currently in insert mode and I want to call undo command, instead of typing `<Esc> <u> <i>`, I want to type `<Alt>+<u>`, and return to insert mode immediately.

I know, you can map all your mappings via imap/inoremap explicitly for every insert mode mapping, but I want to map ALL the normal mode mappings, even those used in my plugins, and this is too much work. Also, I know there's `<Ctrl>+<o>` command to execute only one command in normal mode with returning to starting mode right after, but I want to be able to execute any number of commands in insert mode, not just one, and not to execute any, if I just hold `<Alt>` key (or any modifier I set for this behavior) and then release, not switching to normal mode.

P.S. if someone heard about [vim-clutch](https://github.com/alevchuk/vim-clutch), I want to make the same, not buying extra one pedal for release event, having only one pedal.

thx.

Comment: I believe what you are looking for is emacs

Comment: FDindoof: well, I'm afraid my beard is not too long for it for now, and I don't really have time for switching all my setup with plugins. Will be appreciated for help in what was asked in post)

Comment: How about `ino <A-u> <Esc>ui`?

Comment: well, as I pointed in question, I of course, could do that, for any normal mode command, and those commands added with plugins. But this is too much of work as I should then specify ALL the normal mode commands remapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found solution by myself already - [this](http://www.thebusby.com/2012/07/12-usb-pedals-excellent.html) blog post describes all in depth via using libusb gem.